# FPDF Image Error: Unsupported image type after upgrading to PHP 8

Tags: php, fpdf

I have a signature stored as a base64 string that outputs into PDF reports like so:

```
$image = $row1['signatureString'];     
        
$trimmedSig = substr($image, 22);
        
$pic = 'data:image/gif;base64,' . $trimmedSig;
        
     $pdf->Cell(20, 7, $pdf->Image($pic, 'C', $pdf->GetX(), $pdf->GetY(), 30, 7, 'png'), 'TBL', 0, 'L', false);
```

after I updagraded to PHP 8, I now get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Unsupported image type: 7 in /var/www/html/packages/fpdf182/fpdf.php:271 
Stack trace: 
#0 /var/www/html/packages/fpdf182/fpdf.php(890): FPDF->Error('Unsupported ima...') 
#1 /var/www/html/pdfReports/generatePDF.php(1799): FPDF->Image('data:image/gif;...', 'C', 175.00125, 73.00125, 30, '7', 'png') 
#2 /var/www/html/genPDFReport.php(13): include('/var/www/html/p...') 
#3 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/packages/fpdf182/fpdf.php on line 271
```

Comment: FPDF version 1.82, which you seem to be using, is from 2019-12-07. PHP 8 was release on 26 Nov 2020. Perhaps updating to the lastest version will help? FPDF version 1.84 from 2021-08-28. No guarantees, of course.

Comment: Don't call `Image()` inside `Cell()`. And remove that extra `'C'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
$pic = 'data:image/gif;base64,' . $trimmedSig;
```

but then use

```
Image($pic, 'C', $pdf->GetX(), $pdf->GetY(), 30, 7, 'png')
```

I guess it should be

```
Image($pic, 'C', $pdf->GetX(), $pdf->GetY(), 30, 7, 'gif')
```

Comment: Nicely spotted.

Comment: ...it does say: #1 /var/www/html/pdfReports/generatePDF.php(1799): FPDF->Image('data:image/gif;...', 'C', 175.00125, 73.00125, 30, '7', 'png') :)